# How to handle errors for static fields in Java (JDBC)

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create a class, where I could establish the connection with MySQL database using proper jdbc driver, open connection and close it. I want to do it in a separate class with static final fields, so that user, pwd, dburl credentials are not visible in the code itself, but are taken from the file. However, when I try to assign values to the static fields, I am using methods from classes that potentially throw FileNotFound and SQL Exceptions and I don't know how to handle them in this class. What should I do for my IDE to accept the code I have written? Or do i need to refactor the code somehow and there is a better way to do it? Here's my code:

```
public class DBConnection {

        private static Properties properties = new Properties().load(new FileInputStream("DBProperties"));

        private static final String user = properties.getProperty("user");
        private static final String pwd = properties.getProperty("password");
        private static final String dburl = properties.getProperty("dburl");
        private static Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, pwd);


        public void closeConnection() {
                try {
                        if (myConn != null) {
                                myConn.close();
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't close connection : " + e.getMessage());
                }
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your question doesn't have to do with JDBC, this is basic Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code into a static block:

```
static {

// your code 

}
```